# How to pass not null values @RequestParameter in controller?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, request

I am trying to update an Entity by using spring boot 2.5.3 in the controller method.

```
http://localhost:5000/api/v1/student/1
```

with the following payload.

```
{
    "name":"abc",
    "email":"abc@email.com",
    "dob":"2000-06-14"
}
```

These values are not updated. They are getting null values when I inspected them using a debugger.
Here is my controller method.

```
@PutMapping(path = "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> updateStudent(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestParam(required = false) String name, @RequestParam(required = false) String email) {
    Student savedStudent = studentService.updateStudent(id, name, email);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(savedStudent);
}
```

Email and name are optional.

In debugger: `name:null,email:null`. Why are they getting null values?
What is the correct way to pass values from the controller?

```
@Transactional
// We are not using any query from the repository because we have the service method with transactional annotation.
public Student updateStudent(Long studentId, String name, String email) {
    Student student = studentRepository.findById(studentId).orElseThrow(()->new EntityNotFoundException("Student with id " + studentId + " does not exists."));
    if (name!= null && name.length()>0 && !Objects.equals(name,student.getName())){
        student.setName(name);
    }
    
    if (email!= null && email.length()>0 && !Objects.equals(email,student.getEmail())){
        Optional<Student> optionalStudent = studentRepository.findStudentByEmail(email);
        if (optionalStudent.isPresent()){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Email is already taken");
        }
        student.setEmail(email);
    }
    System.out.println(student);
    Student savedStudent= studentRepository.save(student);
    return savedStudent;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    "name":"abc",
    "email":"abc@email.com",
    "dob":"2000-06-14"
}
```

This is not a request parameter but the request body. You need to create a class and use `@RequestBody` annotation.

```
@Data
public class UpdateStudentRequest {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
}
```

```
@PutMapping(path = "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> updateStudent(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody UpdateStudentRequest request) {
    Student savedStudent = studentService.updateStudent(
            request.getId(), request.getName(), request.getEmail());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(savedStudent);
}
```

If you want to send the request parameters as... URL parameters:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/v1/student/1?name=abc&email=abc@email.com
```

Comment: There should have been a dob that i missed, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't sending it as a param (after `?`).
`http://localhost:5000/api/v1/student/1?name=John` Could do the trick.

Comment: makes sense. ```?name=John``` I should have passed this in the `URL` when using ` @RequestParam`. But I am using postman to pass these values as an object.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are `POST`ing an HTTP request with a content body (being in JSON in your case), you need to map the body using the `@RequestBody` annotation:

```
@PutMapping(path = "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> updateStudent(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody StudentDTO student) {
    Student savedStudent = studentService.updateStudent(
            id, student.getName(), student.getEmail());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(savedStudent);
}
```

The `StudentDTO` would be a lightweight type reflecting your input payload:

```
public class StudentDTO {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String dob;
    // setters and getters
}
```

Otherwise, to keep your `RestController` signature and use the `@RequestParam`etrized fields, you should send a request of following shape:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/v1/student/1?name=abc&email=abc@email.com&dob=2000-06-14
```